# How to get results given a starting and ending date from MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, calendar, fullcalendar

I got the following code on the back of my calendar:

```
// I get this from ajax (start month + end of the month)
$post_date_start = $_POST['date_start']; // start month (always), ie: 2015-09-01
$post_date_ending = $_POST['date_ending']; // end month (always), ie: 2015-09-31

// If I get an event which its duration its between $post_date_start and $post_date ending it works properly as you can see:
SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE start_date >= '$post_date_start' AND ending_date <= '$post_date_ending'
```

**The problem**: it actually returns the results within' these range properly. But if the `start_date` or `ending_date` it is not exactly within this range, it will not return anything.

For example, an event starting on 07-09-2015 and ending on 08-12-2015. It should be displayed on september, october, november and december...). The question is... having those two parameters, how can I do to display the event on every month/year? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a date column to a string literal, forcing the database to implicitly convert one to the other. Apparently, the date is being converted  to a string, and the comparison is done lexicographically. Instead, you should explicitly convert the strings to dates, so the comparison is done by date values:

```
SELECT *
FROM   calendar 
WHERE  start_date  >= STR_TO_DATE('$post_date_start', '%Y-%m-%d') AND  
       ending_date <= STR_TO_DATE('$post_date_ending', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Mandatory comment: 
Using string replacement in SQL statements is a bad idea that leaves your application vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should consider using a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: Hi @Mureinik, I've just tried this and it doesn't works as excepted. It works exactly in the same way I've posted. For example, if $post_date_start is "2015-10-01" and $post_date_ending is "2015-10-31", and I have created an event with the date_start = "2015-10-12" and date_ending "2015-12-12" it won't show anything because it just shows events within October date ranges... Any help please? Thanks!